# react-hightchart: all values in event.point are null

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am using [react-highchart-official](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official) in my project. I need to retrieve some values from the `click` event. In the component, the event listener is set using `plotOptions` like this:

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
          point: {
            events: {
              click: event => {
                this.props.onClick && this.props.onClick(event);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

It gets invoked with `event` object which contains a `point` entry. `point` contains useful information regarding chart.

The chart component is used as:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
// Import Highcharts
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';

// Import our demo components
import Chart from './components/Chart.jsx';

// Load Highcharts modules
require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);

const chartOptions = {
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [[1, 'Highcharts'], [1, 'React'], [3, 'Highsoft']],
      keys: ['y', 'name'],
      type: 'pie'
    }
  ]
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { flag: true };

  onChartClick(event) {
    // All values of event.point are null. Not sure why.
    // Even though it's not a synthetic event.
    console.log(event.point);
    this.setState({ flag: false });

  }

  render() {
    const { flag } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Demos</h1>
        <h2>Highcharts</h2>
        {flag && (
          <Chart
            highcharts={Highcharts}
            onClick={this.onChartClick.bind(this)}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

For some unknown reasons, all the value inside `point` property of click `event` is set to null if I hide the chart. Is there any way I can avoid it? In the actual project on chart `click` I need to redirect user to somewhere. To imitate the situation, I have hidden the chart.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-6ejo5)

Answer (score 1):

This situation exactly shows what happened with your point data, see:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o70mLrnt/

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

  series: [{
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
  }]
});

console.log(chart.series[0].points[1])
chart.destroy();
```

Setting the flag to false unmounting the component which destroys the chart and later console.log doesn't have 'access' to chart and particular point properties.

If you need only a few data from the point a good option will be setting them in the state before the flag will be changed.

Like this - this will keep your point y value.

```
this.setState({
  pointValue: event.point.y
});
```

Another solution which came to my mind is to set the whole point object to some variable, but here the setTimeout needs to be used.

Demo with setState solution and saving object to variable: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-dnbdv

Comment: I am already using setTimeout as a workaround. I thought there might be a better solution to this. Thanks for sharing.